# How Travel Site like Tripadvisor, Airbnb track their user

Tags: proxy, ids, fingerprint, socks5

How Travel Site like Tripadvisor, Airbnb track their user browser fingerprint, ip address and block them to make a second account from the same computer? Using a Socks/Proxy service, VPN would work to make a second registration from the same computer or these website use a large database of IP provider.

Comment: I believe this question belongs to stackoverflow

Comment: I flagged for a migration to the superuser. If you like the nondestructive user handling, this is what I suggest to you.

Comment: What about a cookie on the browser you used? We can't tell you how a particular site does something on their servers.

Comment: @Limit In its current form, this question is not fit for Stack Overflow. It'll get closed as "too broad" or "primarily opinion-based".